# How do I copy an instanced MovieClip multiple times programmatically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, instance

I'm extremely new to Flash/ActionScript, but I've done some C#, Java and C++... Anyway, my question is:

If I have a MovieClip called bird1, and I need to do the following:

```
doStuff(bird1);
doStuff(bird2);
doStuff(bird3);
```

Where bird2 and bird3 are exact copies of bird1, just new instances....
How can I do that until say doStuff(bird30); without having to copy it 30 times and write it all out?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign class name to the symbol of `bird` in the library:

1. open library F11
2. select bird movie clip
3. open symbol properties window (right click->properties)
4. select "Export for AS" check box
5. assign class name for the symbol, for instance `MyBird`

Now you can instantiate you class as many times as you want by the code:

```
doStuff(new MyBird());
```